# What does a graph of "A 7th degree polynomial equation with 4 imaginary roots" look like?

Tags: functions, polynomials, graphing-functions

The question is "Draw a graph that possibly represents the following situation: A 7th degree polynomial equation with 4 imaginary roots." How would I draw this graph?

Comment: The main idea is that it possibly has "three" real zeroes.

Answer (score 7):

Hint: Draw a graph of a polynomial with exactly $7$ real roots, and the usual maxima/minima between roots. Then shift the $x$-axis upwards/downwards so that $4$ of the real roots disappear.

Comment: The simplest example is probably $30+x(x^2-1)(x^2-2^2)(x^2-3^2)$.

Comment: Just wondering, how do we determine the shift value? How would this affect the original equation?, say $f(x)=((1+x^2)^4)((x-5)^3)$ or any other equation that satisfies the question. Thx.

Comment: See http://i.stack.imgur.com/UsfyI.png.

Comment: Your example is not a generic one, because of the triple root at $x=5$. The specific example given above  by lhf is a good one, if you want an equation. But I suspect they want you to show you are aware of the general geometry, and are not really after a specific formula. So do as I wrote, draw a curve that goes to $-\infty$ as $x\to-\infty$, to $\infty$ as  $x\to \infty$, and crosses the $x$-axis $7$ times. Then lift or lower the $x$-axis so exactly $4$ roots disappear. For example there will be $3$ relative minima. Lower the $x$-axis so that two of them are now above the new $x$-axis.

Comment: Thanks and also thanks to @lhf.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one example.
The roots for $f(z)$ are $1,5,9,2+i3,2-i3,7+i4,7-i4$.

[image]